# create simple list within a while loop python

Tags: python, list, function, loops, while-loop

I want to create a simple list within a while loop in python

I'm using this code

```
def get_list(input):
    create_cell = []
    for line in input:
        create_cell.append(line)
    return create_cell

x=0
c = [x,'a','b']
while x < 5:
    new_row = get_list(c)
    print (new_row)
    x = x + 1
```

It gives the following output

```
[0, 'a', 'b']
[0, 'a', 'b']
[0, 'a', 'b']
[0, 'a', 'b']
[0, 'a', 'b']
```

The output what I want is:

```
[0, 'a', 'b']
[1, 'a', 'b']
[2, 'a', 'b']
[3, 'a', 'b']
[4, 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning to `x` doesn't change `c`. You need to update that as well:

```
while x < 5:
    new_row = get_list(c)
    print (new_row)
    x = x + 1
    c[0] = x
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was the problem, now it's fine.